# Non-degenerate bilinear form properties.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, bilinear-form

Given that $v,w\in V$ and $B$ is nondegenerate bilinear form on V

I showed that ${v}^\perp=\operatorname{span}(v)^\perp$ and ${w}^\perp=\operatorname{span}(w)^\perp$. How to show that $v^\perp=w^\perp\implies \operatorname{span}(v)=\operatorname{span}(w)$.

Please help.

Comment: What has $B$ got to do with it?

Comment: If you type out operator names like $\operatorname{span}$, $\TeX$ interprets them as a juxtaposition of variable names and formats them accordingly. To get the right font and spacing, you can use `\operatorname{span}`.

Comment: You need the fact that $(v^\perp)^\perp =\mathrm{span}(v)$.

Comment: Are you assuming $B$ _symmetric_ (or maybe anti-symmetric)? Without it you need to say whether "$\cdot^\perp$" is left-perpendicular or right-permendicular (and you won't have $x^{\perp\perp}=x$).

Answer (score 1):

Since $B$ doesn't appear anywhere after being introduced, I'll assume that you intended to imply that orthogonality refers to $B$-orthogonality.

$a=\langle v,v\rangle w-\langle v,w\rangle v$ is orthogonal to $v$. Since $v^\perp=w^\perp$, it's also orthogonal to $w$. Being a linear combination of $v$ and $w$, it is therefore orthogonal to itself. Since $B$ is non-degenerate, $a=0$. Thus $v$ and $w$ are multiples of each other, so either they have the same span or one of them is zero and the other isn't. That last alternative is impossible, since their orthogonal complements coincide.